# form.Show() center window?

Tags: c#, forms

Why wont this center the form to the screen?

```
        Form2 mySettings = new Form2();
        mySettings.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        mySettings.Show();
```

It works when i use:

```
mySettings.ShowDialog();
```

But the problem with that is that the user cannot access the main form while having Form2 opened at the same time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not set it to `CenterScreen`?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that `FormStartPosition.CenterParent` centers a form on it's parent's location.  Form.Show() does not technically have a parent.  As was already recommended in comments, using `FormStartPosition.CenterScreen` would provide the desired behavior.

`FormStartPosition.CenterParent` should be used primarily when using the `Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window)` overload.

If you need to center on the location of another form, you will need to calculate the new window coordinates yourself using the current Form's location and size.  Then use the `FormStartPosition.Manual` setting to use the provided location and size values in the newly created Form.